# node express backend get route with params in url

Tags: express, knex.js

I am trying to make a controller for a get route with `params` in URL that should look like this: `localhost:3001/service/26` . Where `26` is the `serviceID`. I am using `knex` to query the db. When I access the link above in Postman I get an error in the terminal saying that the `serviceID` column is invalid. I will attach the route, controller and the repository:

```
router.get("/service/:serviceID", serviceController.getService)

const getService = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await serviceRepository.getService(req.params.serviceID);
        res.send(data);
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
}

getService = async (serviceParameters) => {
  const serviceID= serviceParameters.serviceID;
  return await knex("service").select().where("serviceID", serviceID)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getService()` you are trying to access the `serviceID` property of the input, but you are passing `string` as an input. Change your `getService()` function like this:

```js
getService = async (serviceParameters) => {
  const serviceID= serviceParameters;
  return await knex("service").select().where("serviceID", serviceID)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that was the issue!

Comment: Any idea how the axios.get would look ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: const params = useParams();

Comment: await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/service/${params.serviceID}`);